# Host subdomain only on shared godaddy account

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, hosting

Hello I have a domain pointing to a client's managed wordpress account on godaddy. The managed wordpress account does not allow any file management or domain management, but I have a need to keep a subdomain of theirs pointing to a non-wordpress folder on a separate godaddy hosting account. I COULD add the subdomain to the managed wordpress account, but the only option is for it to just point to the wordpress installation; so that's no good.

So far I think I've gathered that I need to set up an A record for the subdomain in the zone file for the domain that points to the IP of my shared server. But once I do this, how do I tell GoDaddy what folder on the server is to be served for that subdomain if I can't have the domain being hosted by 2 seperate godaddy hosting accounts? Pretty sure I don't have access to any apache config files or anything...

I hope that is all clear. Please feel free to request further details.

Comment: Apologies for the limited details. Turns out one IS able to add sub.domain.com as a hosted domain in the hosted domains section. No need to do anything other than that to host the subdomain only, using the shared hosting plan. Did not think that would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the limited details. Turns out one IS able to add sub.domain.com as a hosted domain in the hosted domains section. No need to do anything other than that to host the subdomain only, using the shared hosting plan. Did not think that would be possible.